# How to instantiate a prefab and set its dependencies with PHOTON

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, photon, zenject, prefab

Im trying to isntantiate a prefab with photon bit i have this issue
[image]

Thats because the prefab im trying to instantiate needs some dependencies from de scene like the camera
[image]
[image]

Any ideas how can i do this?? :/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to assign the object in the script. If you need the camera use

```
followObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
```

or

```
followObject = Camera.main;
```

in the Start() method.